# Equivalent of GDI Pen in Direct2D

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi, direct2d

What's the equivalent of GDI Pen in Direct2D?
I know that there is Direct2D brush, but I couldn't figure out if in Direct2D Brush is supposed to be use as a pen?

Comment: Yes, a brush.  Just look at [sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about doing the questioner's job for them

Comment: You need GDI pen not just for a pen, but because you use it with API calls. Equivalent Direct2D calls might accept brushes or immediate color values.

Comment: @HansPassant +1 thanks man!

Comment: @HansPassant You should post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I have no idea how to flesh that out into a helpful post.  Just write the answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

A `Pen` in GDI+ is basically a combination of a Direct2D brush *and* stroke style.

You can see this if you look at WPF's object model: `System.Windows.Media.Pen` has a `Brush` property, and then it also has everything you'd see on Direct2D's `ID2D1StrokeStyle`.

Direct2D is a descendant of WPF's MILcore rendering engine, so this comparison is very relevant. And WPF's MILcore can be considered a descendant of GDI+, having come from the same company and many of the same people.

See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms750441(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of GDI Pen in Direct2D is a Brush.